ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : getting 404 on Azure App Service, but works ok on localhost
I am trying to create and deploy an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API to Azure, but I always get the message:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Here are my exact steps that are very easy to reproduce:
I create an empty folder and then in Powershell I changed directory to the empty folder and executed this:
Write-Host "About to Create the directory" -ForegroundColor Green

mkdir dotnet8coreapi
cd dotnet8coreapi

Write-Host "About to create the solution and projects" -ForegroundColor Green
dotnet new sln
dotnet new webapi -n API --use-controllers

Write-Host "Adding projects to the solution" -ForegroundColor Green
dotnet sln add API/API.csproj

Write-Host "Executing dotnet restore" -ForegroundColor Green
dotnet restore

Write-Host "Finished!" -ForegroundColor Green

The new ASP.NET Core 8 Web API is created. Here is the API.csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

I loaded up the created folder in VS Code. Notice I have a solution file with 1 folder called API that has my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with controllers project.
In a terminal, I execute:
cd api; dotnet watch --no-hot-reload

Everything compiles fine and VS Code auto launches my browser showing Swagger. I test the default weather forecast endpoint and it works fine locally.
I now want to deploy this to an Azure Web App. In VS Code, I have the Azure Tools extension installed and I am signed into my account. I right-click on "App Services" and use the create with advanced option.  I select the run-time stack of .NET 8 LTS and use a Windows OS. The Azure App Service is created successfully.
I now want to deploy my API folder to the Azure Web App Service. I right-click on the newly created AZ Web App Service and select the "Deploy" menu. I select my API folder. I do not select the root folder where the .sln file is, I think the correct thing to do is select the API folder that has the ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with controllers.  Deployment is successful.
I browse to my URL:
https://{name of my app}.azurewebsites.net/swagger 

I get the error:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

I also navigate to URL:
https://{name of my app}.net/weatherforecast 

and again I get:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I also navigated to:
https://{name of my app}.net/api/weatherforecast 

and get the same error.
I searched and read many existing StackOverflow questions that are similar but did not find an answer. I tried deploying both the root folder as well as API folder and get the same results.
In response to a question, here is my program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();


app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();


app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

My gut says I need to change a setting on the newly created Azure Web Service app. I am stumped. Is anyone able to help?
Thanks, Dan

I did try that as well.

I just tried this, created a new ASP.NET Core Web API, published it to Azure (Linux App Service), and navigated to https://{name of my app}.azurewebsites.net/weatherforecast - no problem at all, data is being returned as expected ...

My working theory is you used Linux which does not require a webconfig.json file so it worked.  I used Windows and my gut says I might need to add a webconfig file for it to work....exploring that now.

Can you please share your Program.cs file.

@Harshitha:  I edited my original question with my program.cs

@marc_s: did you deploy the API folder or the root folder?

I deployed from the (full) Visual Studio using the "Publish" function - not from VS Code, sorry, not "fluent" in that ...

I am experiencing the same issue, but I'm on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I have tried deploying using the VS code extension for App Service and also via the az webpapp CLI commands. The deployment lists as sucessfull, still I cant accees anything than the root, all else is 404

@DapperDanh, did you ever resolve this issue?  I'm facing a very similar one where publishing my API via steps in ADO results in the same error, but publishing via Visual Studio does not.

I followed the same steps to create and  deploy web API to Azure app service.
I added this below lines in program.cs , now I can successfully deploy the app.
app.UseSwaggerUI(options  =>
{
options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
if(app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
options.RoutePrefix  =  "swagger";
else
options.RoutePrefix  =  string.Empty;
}

Program.cs:
var  builder  =  WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();  
var  app  =  builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options  =>
{
options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
if(app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
options.RoutePrefix  =  "swagger";
else
options.RoutePrefix  =  string.Empty;
}
);  
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization()
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

Local output:

Deployed via VS Code extension.
Here's the output:


